# sorry page not found message while using valid WOEID for Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests, python-twitter, woe-id

I am trying to generate the trending topics for `WOEID 23424911` (Nepal). It generates the following message

```
TwitterError: [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist.', u'code': 34}]
```

code used:

```
import twitter
consumer_key=.....
consumer_secret=......
access_token=.......
access_token_secret=.....
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key, consumer_secret,access_token, access_token_secret)
print api.GetTrendsWoeid(woeid=23424911, exclude=None)
```

However, interestingly for `WOEID 23424848` (India), the topics are topics are generated.

WOEID could be extracted from

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+geo.places+where+text+=+%27Nepal%27
```

Any thoughts why I am getting this error?

Comment: maybe there is no information for Nepal. Can you get it directly on Twitter page ?

Comment: It's an entire country. If its neighbouring country India has it, it should. But I might be mistaken.

Comment: I tried to set it directly on Twitter page and it couldn't find Nepal.

Comment: @furas thank you. Could this be a twitter feature issue? If so where do I raise the issue, if you have an idea?

Comment: as for me it is not issue - simple maybe they don't have tweets about Nepal so they don't have trends for Nepal.

Comment: I get it what you said but question more is to find trending topics within Nepal. As far as I know there are hundreds of active twitter users in that country if not thousands. Meaning trying to find trending topics for that specific geography. If there are any other suggested ways please let me know.